# Getting error in Spyder Anaconda from Keras Libraries CNN: WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda

**I am trying to implement the Keras libraries for Convolutional Neural Networks on my Spyder IDE using Anaconda as such:**

```
from keras.models import Sequential     
from keras.layers import Conv2D  
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D   
from keras.layers import Flatten        
from keras.layers import Dense
```

**When I just execute this piece of code, I get this error:**

```
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/shubh/Desktop/P14-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/Convolutional_Neural_Networks/myCNN.py')
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
```

I downgraded from Python 3.7 to 3.6 so I can use Keras and Tensorflow. I did an Artificial Neural Network program and it worked successfully. But when I import these libraries for CNN, I am getting these errors. And I understand it says missing Tensorboard installation, how if this is the solution, please advise me on how to do this as I haven't seen any sources that have worked for me. Again, I use anaconda, not pip.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the contents of the environment. _Again, I use anaconda, not pip._ Anaconda and pip fulfill different purposes.

Comment: A quick google search for some of the warnings returns multiple results, have you consulted those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a warning. Have you tried running your CNN?

[Here is a Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2968) that talks about what you are seeing

Comment: Great news! It worked! I am new to ML/DL. I was still able to successfully manage to train my CNN once I ran my whole code, not just that importing section. Thank you, Anna!

Comment: @ShubhangJani glad it worked. If my answer helped and was correct, please accept it so other people can find it.

Answer (score 1):

This eliminated the warning for me:

```
pip uninstall tensorboard
pip install tensorboard
```

I now have tensorflow version 2.4.1 and tensorboard version 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Running `conda install Tensorboard` in the terminal worked for me.